# Cypress cy.visit("/") cannot detect that page load after first run

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a simple test script to load page and fill login form. On first run everything is ok. On next runs cypress just waits the page to load (until timeout), but page load has finished already.
I have checked all network requests and and there are no pending request.

My cypress config file:

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        baseUrl: "https://pos.clopos.com/",
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            // implement node event listeners here
        },
        viewportWidth: 1024,
        viewportHeight: 768,
    },

});
```

And my test file:

```
describe('Authorisation tests', () => {

    it('Should login to pin view', () => {
        cy.clearAllLocalStorage();
        cy.clearAllSessionStorage();
        cy.clearAllCookies();

        cy.visit('/', { timeout: 10000 });

        cy.get('#brand').type("not_existing_brand");
        cy.contains("Next").click();
        cy.get(".error-msg").should("be.visible").should("contain", "Sorry, but the Brand name notexistingbrand does not exist");


    });
})
```